# Why Spring Social Authentication is NULL?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-social

I have a simple Spring MVC application that I run using Eclipse that connects to LinkedIn and prints the user connections. The connection to LinkedIn is done by Spring Social.

The application worked fine until I added the Authentication code to the ConnectionRepository bean:

```
@Bean
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public ConnectionRepository connectionRepository() {

    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .getAuthentication();
    if (authentication == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Unable to get a ConnectionRepository: no user signed in");
    }

    return usersConnectionRepository().createConnectionRepository(
            "testUser");
}
```

When I run the application I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get a ConnectionRepository: no user signed in
at com.zomba.web.config.SocialConfig.connectionRepository(SocialConfig.java:69)
at com.zomba.web.config.SocialConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8f50f43e.CGLIB$connectionRepository$2(<generated>)
at com.zomba.web.config.SocialConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8f50f43e$$FastClassByCGLIB$$a916f011.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:286)
at com.jobomy.web.config.SocialConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8f50f43e.connectionRepository(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:160)
```

The cause of this error is that the Authentication is NULL.

Why is the connectionRepository bean called before a request is done? How should I deal with it?

Here some of my configuration files:

**WebMvcConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.zomba.web.controllers","com.zomba.web.services"}, 
    excludeFilters = { @ComponentScan.Filter(Configuration.class) })
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
      registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("/webjars/");
      registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/css/");
      registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**").addResourceLocations("/img/");
  }

....

}
```

**SocialConfig**

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:linkedin.properties")

public class SocialConfig {
    @Inject
    private Environment environment;

    @Inject
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Inject
    private TextEncryptor textEncryptor;


    /**
     * Factory for Social connections. You could add more special factories
     * here.
     */
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator() {
        ConnectionFactoryRegistry registry = new ConnectionFactoryRegistry();
        registry.addConnectionFactory(new LinkedInConnectionFactory(environment
                .getProperty("linkedin.consumerKey"), environment
                .getProperty("linkedin.consumerSecret")));
        return registry;
    }

    @Bean
    public UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository() {
        return new JdbcUsersConnectionRepository(dataSource,
                connectionFactoryLocator(), textEncryptor);
    }

    /**
     * Bean that control user connection. You should use real user Id for
     * application instead testUser here.
     */
    @Bean
    @Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
    public ConnectionRepository connectionRepository() {

        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .getAuthentication();
        if (authentication == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Unable to get a ConnectionRepository: no user signed in");
        }

        return usersConnectionRepository().createConnectionRepository(
                "testUser");
    }
}
```

PLEASE HELP....

Answer (score -2):

please add dependencies in this(1.0.0.RC4) version:

```
<org.springframework.social.linkedin-version>1.0.0.RC4</org.springframework.social.linkedin-version>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-social-linkedin</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.social.linkedin-version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-social-web</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.social-version}</version>
</dependency>
```